# How can I get all of my Gmail contacts into my Mac Contacts?

Tags: gmail, contacts

I was able to import all of my Gmail contacts into my iPhone but my Mac doesn't include them.  How can I get all of my Gmail contacts into my Mac contacts app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Lion/Mountain Lion, go to the Preferences on your Contact app, choose Accounts and then On My Mac, and there should be a checkbox Synchronize with Google, you will just need to provide your Gmail credentials.
Just as a precaution, make a backup of your contacts first. Just need to go to Gmail, select Contacts, then the More button, Export to download all your contacts to your hard drive.

Comment: out of curiosity, why the need to make a backup of contacts first ?

Comment: Just in case the Contacts app makes some unexpected changes to your gmail contacts and mess them up.

Comment: This was really helpful! Is there a way to keep synching the contacts? So if I add one to my gmail contacts it will automatically add it to the apple mail/contacts client? Thanks so much!

Comment: @Alison consider posting this as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way to do this. Pull up your contacts in Gmail, select the "more" botton, click the export contacts option, it will give you the option to export them as vCards. Export as vCards to the desktop. Pull up mac contacts, click import and select the file you dropped on the desktop. You are done.

Comment: easier and safer as leftover cruft from apple contacts doesn't corrupt google contacts